# How to access phone Call Log in Ionic Hybrid App(Cordova) and how to get the call back to our app after the call is ended from the our mobile app?

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to mobile app development. I am developing the ***Hybrid Mobile app using IONIC FRAMEWORK 2(ANGULAR 2)***. I am having following questions.

1.) Is there any plugin available for accessing the phone call log from both IOS/Android? I have tried the following plugin but I don't know how to get the call log using that. ([Cordova CallLog for andriod](https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin)). and this plug in is only for android not for ios.

2.) The user will call from our mobile app, and the system will use the native calling. So, after the call has ended, I need a Callback to our app saying that whether the call has Rejected or Successfully Completed?

Appreciate your help!